# Bings Maps API v8 Zoom on Chrome

Tags: api, https, zooming, bing-maps, bing

Has anybody had problems with Chrome?  I have been updating a map at HTTPS, which works fine with all browsers under HTTP. Everything works except the zoom control, which I cannot understand as it is part of the BIng map.

I have disabled various items and the inbuilt zoom controls still do not work.  In addition I have changed the order of loading without success.

The full map at https://sysmaps.co.uk/sysmaps_bing.html and the previous unsecured map at http://www.sysmaps.co.uk/sysmaps_bing.html

Any help appreciated - I have spent hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

For others, this issue was also asked on the Bing Maps MSDN forums here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cfd9d19b-2af5-4f9d-952e-2aec06142857/bing-maps-api-v8-zoom-control-not-working?forum=bingmaps and was resolved and was caused by a coding error in the users application.